# how to set Anonymous login in ejabberd server in ejabberd.yml

Tags: ejabberd

Hi i want to set anonymous login for ejabberd server.I was trying to set it in ejabbedd.yml. This is my config which i was trying with

Anonymous login support:
 host_config:
   "domain":
     auth_method: anonymous
     anonymous_protocol: sasl_anon

Comment: What does not work ? What is the traffic you send from the client and what does the server reply ?

Comment: i am trying out ejabberd with converse.js , the above configuration is set in ejabberd.yml file and converse.js i configurred as  converse.initialize({
            websocket_url: 'ws://********:5280/websocket', // Please use this connection manager only for testing purposes
            auto_login: true,
            jid: 'administrator@Vostro-3558-PC',
            authentication: 'anonymous',
            
        }); it just stays as connecting in chat UI

Comment: Read the log: What do you have in ejabberd log in debug mode ?